# How to efficiently setup column data types in SQL from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

More of a theoretical question as to the best way to set something up.

I have quite a large dataframe in `pandas` (roughly 330 columns) and I am hoping to transfer it into a table in SQL Server.

My current process has been to export the dataframe as a `.csv` and then use the `Import Flat File` function to first of all create the table, and then in future I have a direct connection setup in Python to interact. For smaller dataframes this has worked fine as it has been easier to change data column types and eventually get it to work.

When doing it on the larger dataframes my problem is that I am frequently getting the following message:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Error inserting data into table. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Import.Wizard)
>
> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column. (System.Data)
>
> String or binary data would be truncated. (System.Data)

It doesn't give me a specific column as to what is causing the problem so is there any way to more efficiently get this data in as opposed to going through each column manually?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: thanks - cna you create a new table in SQL from `sqlalchemy`?

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, this is in fact an issue when you are trying to write a string value into a column, the size limit is exceeded. Either you may increase the column size limit or try truncating before inserting.
Let's say column `A` in `df` is of type `varchar(500)`, Try the following before insertion :-

`df.A=df.A.apply(lambda x: str(x)[:500])`

Below is the sqlalchemy alternative for the insertion.

```
connect_str="mssql+pyodbc://<username>:<password>@<dsnname>"
```

To create a connection -

```
engine = create_engine(connect_str)
```

Create the table -

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Integer

m = MetaData()
t = Table('example', m,
        Column('column_1', Integer),
        Column('column_2', Integer)),
        ...)
m.create_all(engine)
```

Once created, do the following :-

```
df.to_sql('example', if_exists='append')
```

Comment: Thanks ill give this a go. Do I need to manually add the column names? there are 300 so thats what I am trying to avoid doing

Comment: I prefer creating the table manually first and then insert records, however `sqlalchemy` allows you to insert without creating the table as well.

Comment: Thanks Anant. My issue is there are 300 columns so I’m trying to avoid adding them manually (without the data type errors)

Comment: You may set the column datatype prior to insertion. Let us assume there are lesser number of string columns then you may try to cast it first, `df.A=df.A.astype(str)` and then insert.